# Render HTML Tags in SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have markup text (HTML tags) in one of the SQLView\columns, which I have to show in a Tablix report as a formatted text in one column. Markup is for bold, italic, underline.

I could enable the HTML in Text box but not in Tablix. Could you please suggest what is the option for getting HTML tags in my report.

Country is default selected based on the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you'll need to create a placeholder in the textbox/field where you have the HTML and set your value in the placeholder expression.  There's an option for "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles".  However, certain HTML tags are not supported by SSRS.  [This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) shows a complete list of supported HTML tags.

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks Steve for replying this